# Independent and Identically Distributed Random Variables, with 0.01 and 0.99

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, independence

good day

Can anybody help me? thanks

Let ${X_i}$ Independent and Identically Distributed Random Variables as normals with mean $μ$ and standard deviation 2, What is the minimum value of n such that $P(|\dfrac{S_n}{n}-μ|<.01) \geq .99$

Thanks

Independent and Identically Distributed Random Variables

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What are your thoughts so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: i literally don't know what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gives you $X\sim N(\mu, 4)$, then $S\sim N(n\mu, 4n)$.

So $$\begin{split}P(|\frac {S-n\mu}{n}|<.01)&=P(|\frac{S-n\mu}{2\sqrt n}|<.005\sqrt n)\\
&=P(|Z|<.005\sqrt n)\ge .99\end{split}$$

Thus you need to find the quantile function $\Phi^{-1}.995$ to find a lower bound for $.005\sqrt n$, say you get z*. Then solve $.005\sqrt n\ge z^*$ to get the minimum value of n. Don’t forget to round up to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{S_n}{n}$ is normal with mean $\mu$ and standard devation $\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}$.  To get your answer look up table of normal distribution.